# Launch chrome with OS data from another hard disk

Tags: google-chrome, data-recovery

I usually setup chrome (browser) to restore windows and tabs from last time.

I recently crashed a ubuntu install, but managed to recover the `/home` directory. (And all others - it just won't boot anymore.)

I've got another computer with Chrome installed.

How can I launch chrome on another computer and restore the windows and tabs as recorded on the other hard disk?

Essentially I am assuming one can find a directory in which chrome stores all its data required to restore tabs and windows. Then copy this from my hard disk from the old system to the hard disk of my system which will boot. I hope then when I run chrome it will pickup the data copied across and restore my browsing session.

Is this possible?

Both computers run ubuntu 16.04 by the way.

Comment: Not the answer I was aiming for, but it can be done using chrome apparently: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2591582?hl=en-GB

Comment: You can answer your own question, then you can mark it as resolved and other people can find it more easily in the future! :)

Comment: Ok I'll move it later today

Answer (score 0):

## Instructions for Chromium and Chrome

The user data is in `~/.config/chrome` [for example] - first make a backup of your current browser status

```
sudo mv ~/.config/chrome ~/.config/chrome-backup
```

Then copy across from external disk

```
sudo cp -r /media/user/.../home/username/.config/chrome ~/.config
```

**Not sure about other browsers yet**

Comment: Other browsers are not important since the question is about Chrome, nevertheless for Firefox (and Thunderbird) it's `~/.mozilla`.